# sort --check: continue past first disorder

Tags: sort, coreutils

I would like to get a list of all the places in a large file where the keys decrease from a previous line.

I can check if the file is sorted using sort:

```
sort -cns -k1.14,1.15 -k1.1,1.10 file.txt
```

But it only tells me about the first failure to be sorted (`sort: file.txt:42: disorder: <bad line>`.)

Can I get it to continue, and tell me about further disorders in the file?

Comment: maybe wrap a sed loop around it that only prints from (disordered line + 1) each time?